# User is not getting authenticated (cookies not getting set) after SAML getting processed successfully

Tags: saml-2.0, kentor-authservices, sustainsys-saml2

I am using an idp initiated SSO flow. I am using Kentor.AuthServices using OWIN middleware.

Most of the flow works except, user identity is not getting *SET* when the control reaches my callback method after successfully processing the SAML response.

Setting in web.config:

```
<kentor.authServices entityId="https://one-staging.com/MVSAMLServiceProvider" 
                     returnUrl="https://5814a15e.ngrok.io/api/Account/UnsolicitedExternalLogin">
    <identityProviders>
      <add entityId="https://shibidp.edu/idp/shibboleth"
          metadataLocation = "~/Providers/SAML2/Metadata/shibidp.edu.xml"
          allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="false" 
          disableOutboundLogoutRequests="false"
          binding="HttpRedirect">
      </add>
      <add entityId="abb:one:saml20:idp"
           metadataLocation="~/Providers/SAML2/Metadata/abb.xml"
           allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true"
           disableOutboundLogoutRequests="false"
           binding="HttpRedirect">
      </add>
    </identityProviders>
</kentor.authServices>
```

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
        AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat()
    };

    // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);

    googleAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientId"],
        ClientSecret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientSecret"],
        Provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
    };
    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleAuthOptions);


    app.Use(async (Context, next) =>{await next.Invoke();});    
    app.UseKentorAuthServicesAuthentication(CreateSAMLAuthServicesOptions());
    app.Use(async (Context, next) =>{await next.Invoke();});
}
```

Here are the Kentor logs (no errors in the logs):

```
DEBUG 2018-12-28 14:02:32,682  8859ms emv-authService-logger MoveNext           - Received unsolicited Saml Response _t0r6DHtsGygxkYcfNzdkEs72.M which is allowed for idp abb:one:saml20:idp
DEBUG 2018-12-28 14:02:32,729  8906ms emv-authService-logger MoveNext           - Signature validation passed for Saml Response _t0r6DHtsGygxkYcfNzdkEs72.M
DEBUG 2018-12-28 14:02:32,729  8906ms emv-authService-logger MoveNext           - Extracted SAML assertion oN4v.k9x2GE7s5S8OdeNWS.93j9
DEBUG 2018-12-28 14:02:32,729  8906ms emv-authService-logger MoveNext           - Validated conditions for SAML2 Response _t0r6DHtsGygxkYcfNzdkEs72.M
INFO  2018-12-28 14:02:32,729  8906ms emv-authService-logger ProcessResponse    - Successfully processed SAML response _t0r6DHtsGygxkYcfNzdkEs72.M and authenticated 10035094
```

Finally my redirect method:

```
[OverrideAuthentication]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("UnsolicitedExternalLogin", Name = "UnsolicitedExternalLogin")]
public async void GetUnsolicitedExternalLogin()
{
    bool isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; //getting false
}
```

I have unfortunately been stuck with this problem for a week now. I'm sure this is really close to getting done, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In `GetUnsolicitedExternalLogin`, what does the `User.Identity` object look like. The `IsAuthenticated` property is not always reliable, the logic behind it is a bit peculiar.

Comment: This is what it looks like: [User object](https://ibb.co/bd3qtbJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, I think that there is a mismatch on authentication schemes.

In the pipeline setup, a cookie middleware for the external authentication scheme is setup. But in the `GetUnsolicitedExternalLogin` method, the `ApplicationCookie` scheme is referenced. Change it to reference the external scheme instead.

It is also a good idea to check if the redirect from `~/AuthServices/Acs` to `GetUnsolicitedExternalLogin` sets an external authentication cookie.

Comment: Yep! That was the issue. Changing it to DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie make it work. THANK YOU so much!!!!!!!

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted (and if you want to give me some extra points also upvote it). Writing a thank you comment is not necessary :)